# Unknown Tag 'dajaxice_js_import' when setting up Dajaxice with Coffin

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Reference:

- [Dajaxice Installation Documentation](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/wiki/Installation)

In my Django app, I am trying to install/use Dajaxice. I've loaded the egg with easy_install just fine--I can `import` it in django's shell. I have come to the point in the installation guide where you load the Dajaxice javascript. I entered the following in my base.html template:

```
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}
```

and later, in `<head>`:

```
{% dajaxice_js_import %}
```

On this line I get a TemplateSyntaxError, "Encountered unknown tag 'dajaxice_js_import'".

Here's my TEMPLATE_LOADERS content in settings.py:

```
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
```

I have Coffin installed, and it looks like the error is getting raised there / in Jinja2 (traceback goes through coffin egg and exception is raised in jinja2/environment).

Now, I expect the answer is that I'll have to write a custom tag with coffin, but what I've tried does not work. So my questions are:

Is the problem with Coffin? If so, how would I fix it / what would the code for a custom template tag code look like?

Comment: Figured one thing out: if I switch back to not using Coffin, this no longer happens. This is definitely a Coffin thing. The question becomes: how do I get it to work with Coffin?

Comment: I assume you assured dajaxice is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 1):

I just gave up on this and wrote my own ajax functions. I'm still not sure how I would go about solving this, but the answer would be in custom templating in Coffin. The support/documentation for that seems a little iffy, though.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to add dajax and dajaxice to list of installed apps.
Should be like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'dajax',
        'dajaxice',
)
```

Please also check urls.py for dajaxice_autodiscover() call